# Find the element that has the max first part in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

For a list of `list={{x1,y1},{x2,y2}, ..., {xn,yn}}`, how to find the element with the maximum value of the 1st coordinate, i.e. `{xmax, yi}`, including its position? It may be something like `Map[(Max[#1, _]) &, list]` Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just look up [`MaximalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy.html) in the documentation: `maxbyfirst = MaximalBy[list, First]` and use `Position`.

Comment: I just noticed your title says "second part" and the question says "1st coordinate". Please make it consistent.

Comment: @Syed thanks, title modified

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, {20, 2}]

TakeLargestBy[lst-> {"Element","Index"},First, 1]//Catenate

(* {{89, 95}, 16} *)
```

Or, perhaps you want:

```
TakeLargest[lst[[All,1]]-> {"Element","Index"}, 1]
(* {{89, 16}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear[list];
list = {{2, 3}, {8, 5}, {4, 2}};
Ordering[list[[;; , 1]], -1] // First
list[[%]]
```

> `2`

> `{8,5}`

Answer (score 2):

```
alist = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, {20, 2}]

Max[alist[[All, 1]]]

pos = Position[alist, {Max[alist[[All, 1]]], _}]

Extract[alist, pos]
```